# What is this 12" long, 3/16" dia, double arm hardware item?

Tags: hardware

About 12" long, 3/16 diameter. I tried google image search but nothing came close. Looks like some kind of hardware store display arm, but am trying to find the specific application name to find others like it.

[image: 12" x 3/16"]

Found image (thanks to isherwood)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeWWS.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It used to have a two-pronged metal or plastic base which engaged with perforated pegboard. The upper arm is a mount for a price tag holder.

Search something like "[pegboard display hook](https://www.google.com/search?q=pegboard%20display%20hook&tbm=isch)".

[image]

<sub>[source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2FSouthern-Imperial-R33-4-212-Fastback-Scan%2Fdp%2FB0002YRL0G&psig=AOvVaw2DbzGmArHIrHC06UvvELjQ&ust=1683395921986000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CBIQjhxqFwoTCJDJ-9Hg3v4CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAL)</sub>